# How to flatten nested struct using PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

How to flatten nested struct using PySpark?

Link to dataset
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-xOpd2B7MDgS1t4ekfipHSerIm6JMz9e/view?usp=sharing

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackovrflow is not the place to post a homework assignment and expect someone to solve it...

Comment: @Phantoms It's not a homework assignment :D

Comment: ok, but don't expect from us to do the whole work for you. Show us what you got and how we can help you.

Comment: I am having issues with just flattening nested struct data, I just tried to explain the scenario and gave the dataset.

Comment: @Phantoms this is what I have - need to flatten this. I have added an image into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with Phantoms that it is very basic to flatten a df still if you still haven't figured it out you can use below function to flatten your df

```
def flattenNestedData(nestedDF):
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col
  from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,ArrayType
  try:
       ##Fetching Complex Datatype Columns from Schema
       fieldNames = dict([(field.name, field.dataType) for field in nestedDF.schema.fields if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or type(field.dataType) == StructType]) 
       while len(fieldNames)!=0:
         fieldName=list(fieldNames.keys())[0]
         print ("Processing :"+fieldName+" Type : "+str(type(fieldNames[fieldName])))
         if type(fieldNames[fieldName]) == StructType:
           extractedFields = [col(fieldName +'.'+ innerColName).alias(fieldName+"_"+innerColName) for innerColName in [ colName.name for colName in fieldNames[fieldName]]]
           nestedDF=nestedDF.select("*", *extractedFields).drop(fieldName)
    
         elif type(fieldNames[fieldName]) == ArrayType: 
           nestedDF=nestedDF.withColumn(fieldName,explode_outer(fieldName))
    
         fieldNames = dict([(field.name, field.dataType) for field in nestedDF.schema.fields if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or type(field.dataType) == StructType])   
         
       return nestedDF

      
  except Exception as err:
    raise Exception("Error Occured at while flattening the dataframe : " + str(err))
```

You can remove Arraytype check if you don't want to explode those

Comment: thanks for your reply. This helped but some small issue is there. Everything looks fine but I am unable to flatten 2 elements (wheels and centroid)

Comment: I tired to flatten Z0ppWyDrlOkVCdt2Y720YnSS3XVInC and wheels was looking fine to me so can you share an example where you feel its not working fine also looking at wheels column you will need to keep array explode as the struct column is inside array column