# Explode a table with a List of Jsons with Pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I have this JSON schema which I parsed to a temp. table in pySpark:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- meta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- view: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- approvals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- reviewedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- reviewedAutomatically: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submissionDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- permissionType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submissionId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submissionObject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submissionOutcome: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submissionOutcomeApplication: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- failureCount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submittedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submitter: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- workflowId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- assetType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attribution: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attributionLink: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- averageRating: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- clientContext: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- clientContextVariables: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- cachedContents: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- average: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- cardinality: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- largest: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- non_null: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- not_null: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- null: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- smallest: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sum: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- top: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dataTypeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- fieldName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- format: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- align: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- mask: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- noCommas: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- precisionStyle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- renderTypeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tableColumnId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- width: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- displayType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- downloadCount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- grants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- inherited: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hideFromCatalog: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hideFromDataJson: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- indexUpdatedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- attachments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- assetId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- availableDisplayTypes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- custom_fields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Additional Resources: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- See Also: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Dataset Information: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Agency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Dataset Summary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Contact Information: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Coverage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Data Frequency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Dataset Owner: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Granularity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Office/Division: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Posting Frequency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Time Period: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Units: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Disclaimers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Limitations: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Local Data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- County Filter: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- County_Column: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- filterCondition: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- includeAuto: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- multiSelect: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- operator: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tableColumnId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- 583607: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- advanced: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- unifiedVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rdfClass: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rdfSubject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- renderTypeConfig: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- visible: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- table: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rowLabel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- newBackend: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- numberOfComments: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- oid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- owner: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlLarge: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlMedium: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlSmall: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- screenName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- provenance: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationAppendEnabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationDate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationGroup: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationStage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rights: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- rowClass: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rowsUpdatedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rowsUpdatedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tableAuthor: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlLarge: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlMedium: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlSmall: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- screenName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tableId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- totalTimesRated: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- viewCount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- viewLastModified: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- viewType: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to answer the question: "How can you bring these nested fields up to the top level in a DataFrame?". I have no idea how I can think of solving this. I already tried to modify the schema by the .withColumn, and parsing another dataframe schema, idk. The best scenario here would be kind of a guide cause I didn't find complex things like this on the internet.

Comment: there are a few options given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271398/flatten-nested-spark-dataframe)

Comment: I have tried creating a function to flatten [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72303504/19075771)